# Silverlight HttpWebRequest content length empty, WTF?

Tags: c#, silverlight, httpwebrequest

When I run the following code the RESTful web service receiving the request has an empty body (content length = 0) and I don't know why?

If I run Fiddler whilst debugging the request executes as expected and the server receives the body, I guess I'm not configuing something for the request any ideas?

```
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer.Add(uri, new Cookie("SSOToken", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SsoToken)));
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        request.BeginGetRequestStream(ar1 =>
        {
            var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

            var stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(ar1);
            stream.Write(byteArray, 0, data.Length);
            stream.Close();

            request.BeginGetResponse(ar2 => HandleSearchCompleted(ar2, request, action), state);
        }, state);
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that it works when you're using Fiddler, but doesn't work when you don't? What happens if you use Wireshark to debug instead of Fiddler?

Comment: that is exactly what I'm saying Jon, works when Fiddler is enabled!

Comment: never used wireshark, easy to setup ?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of server is it? If the client is using HTTP/1.1 protocol (which is what it uses by default) then it wont post the entire entity body with the request. Instead it first just sends the headers, with an Expect: 100-continue header...

> POST /url HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: hostname
>
> Content-Length: 128
>
> Expect: 100-continue

At this point, if the server is ready to accept the data, it should reply with:

> HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

So, it could be that you are posting to a buggy server that is not understanding the request correctly. That is why, when you post through Fiddler, the server ends up getting the entity because fiddler is probably sending the request headers and entity body to the server (after doing the HTTP/1.1 100 continue handshake with the client).

Workarounds?

1. Try setting Expect100Continue=false on the HttpWebRequest.
2. Try using HTTP/1.0 protocol.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do would be to fix the bug in the code.  The code assumes the total number of bytes to be sent will be the number of characters in the `data` string.  This isn't true if the string contains characters outside the basic ASCII character set.

You should first acquire the UTF8 byte array and use the length of this array as ContentLength and make sure you send the whole array.

Comment: good point, but I don't think it will be outside the basic ASCII range, will let you know the outcome...

Comment: corrected the bug and it is still happening, interestingly it works in FF (ver 2.6.10) but it still fails to send the request body in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting the content type to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' instead of 'text/xml', URL-encoding the xml content, and assigning it to a variable in the request body.  I experienced this same behavior while trying to use Request.Form on the server side to access the data, until I set the content type correctly.  If you're using some other method on the server to get the raw data, then this may not apply.