# How to set the Expect header in Silverlight 4.0 to ignore HTTP status code 100

Tags: silverlight, httpwebrequest, http-headers

I want the Silverlight 4.0 client to ignore '100-continue' response code from a RESTful resource service, to do this i need to be able to set the Expect header - ' Expect: 100-continue' is this possible with the HttpWebRequest class?

All the normal ways of doing this are not supported in Silverlight 4.0.

Comment: How are 100 response codes causing you problems?  Why do you believe that setting this header will cause the client to ignore the responses?  Are you using browser or client http?

Comment: bcease the server is receiving a content length = 0, no body to the request...

Comment: see question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805725/silverlight-httpwebrequest-content-length-empty-wtf

Comment: So the Expect100Continue property on the HttpWebRequest is not supported in Silverlight?

Comment: you are not able to set 'Expect' header in Silverlight 4.0 - it throws an exception

Comment: and no Expect100Continue  is not supported in SL 4

Comment: How about protocol version? Can you use HTTP/1.0 as the version?

Answer (score 0):

Can you look at the Silverlight security policy? You have to add the "Expect" header to the list of allowed headers in you clientaccesspolicy.xml. Give that a try.

Comment: the client access policy file already has the wildcard to allow all headers with - http-request-headers="*"